# HTML code indentation issues in google chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, indentation

> click this links to see the screenshots

- [full source code of the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NOK1.png)
- [source code of the external    file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsYey.png)
- [full source code of the home page (in google chrome    **inspect
  view**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peX3z.png)
- [full source code of the home page (in google chrome **page source
  view**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA3Vm.png)

I have been keeping the code indentation in that web pages from the beginning in my code editor. but when i see my site on google chrome, the indentation is not set properly. can I know why is this? I googled this, yet coudn't find an answer or a solution.

Comment: The code is intended perfectly.  -1

Comment: Did you see the source codes of them in google chrome view? (screen shot 3 and 4)? in that the indentation is not intended properly

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peX3z.png
in this screenshot,  the div class "a" 's closing tag is displaying at another place which is not nice. 
The colsing tag has to be displayed at the indent line where the tag has started as in the code editor.

Comment: Took back the -1. How does the source code intendation affect you?

Comment: @MrigankPawagi the source code indentation doesn't affect me. I mean i don't get any errors due to the indentation. but the problem is when i just inspect it, the indentation is not perfect as it's not indented like in my code editor

Comment: You should Use the page source in that case.

Comment: I have seen that on page source as well. this is the screenshot of it https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA3Vm.png
in that did you notice that the div class name "new" 's ending tag is displaying out the the indentation

Comment: For I now know how serious the `bug` is, +1  :P

Comment: Can you suggest me anything for this? @MrigankPawagi.

Comment: If you try this out from  your own PC, you can come across this either @MrigankPawagi

Comment: @MrigankPawagi if you see the all those 4 screenshots you can understand the issue even clearly

Comment: What do you see in the `Network` Tab?

Comment: there is no any data to display in network tab as it is a simple HTML code

Comment: I mean, how does the indentation occur in PREVIEW ?

Comment: In preview, the website looks perfect with no issues.

Comment: Only the problem is the indentation when inspecting it , and seeing the source code in chrome as well

Answer (score 1):

It is not Google Chrome's fault. Your files simply get compiled to this form, the browser displays them exactly as they look like.

But why they look like this? In your case PHP's `include` does only purely textual replacement, as in the picture bellow:
[image]

The effect is the same as if you copied the contents of the external file and pasted them to the main file, replacing the `include` tag.

If you would really insist on having the code indented properly after the `include` does its job, you would have to add new spaces at the beginning of each line (but first) of the included file. It would shift the text to the right (in this case 4 spaces) and in the result the indentation would be preserved.

However, I'd discourage you from doing so -- it is only the code that is generated, probably no one is going to work with the compiled result. Proper formatting of code is only meant to make the human work easier -- it has no effect on how the page will eventually look like, when rendered by browser. Thus, it probably would suffice if you kept the two source files formatted as they currently are and left the output as is, even though it is not indented well.

If you'd like to have the code properly formatted in the *page source* view, please remember that you can simply use the "pretty print" button in the lower left corner of the preview:[image]

Comment: In that external file, all the codes have indentations.
But once I have included the external file in the main file, the first line of the external file looks good (it is not out of the indentation) as it is in the external file (div class = 'new'). But Why is the div class = ''sub_a" is out of its indentation once I have included the external file in the main file then? (Your explanation photo shows that very well either though)

Comment: I have extended the answer (and prepared a new photo for you :) )